# Corona SDK - Textfield and ios8

Tags: ios8, coronasdk, native, textfield

My friend has a problem with a textfield with ios8. He has a chat style app that have that textfield on the bottom of the app that is moving over the keyboard that appear if he tap on it. Everything work well, but with new iOS there is the problem of the autocorrector that can appear or not. How he can detect if autocorrector is appearing or not?

I put some image for make you understand better my problem:

This image is with the autocorrect not activated
[image: This image is with the autocorrect not activated]

This image is with the autocorrect activated
[image: This image is with the autocorrect activated]

He needs that in both cases he can view the textfield of text.

Regards,
Roberto

Comment: Anything tried? Codes?

Comment: No... nothing... he is searching an handler or something like that... if he can't detect something that detect that activation he can't write any code... the problem is not how to move it... the problem is how to handle it with corona sdk.